# Strongly zero-dimensinal spaces that are homeomorphic to other spaces under certain conditions

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets, separable-spaces, dimensional-analysis, metrizability

According to a theorem from van Engelen: [Homogeneous zero-dimensional absolute Borel sets](https://search.library.wisc.edu/catalog/999919779802121) (1986):

**Theorem:** *If $X$ is a separable metrizable zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma\delta}$ that is nowhere $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and of the first category (in itself), then $X \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\omega$ .*

**My question** is: do similar conditions as im the Theorem apply for any other spaces that are **strongly** zero-dimensional?

If not with similar assumptions, the conditions can be even very different from those in the theorem. But I am interested whether for any other strongly zero-dimensional space $Y$, there exists $X$ such that **$X \simeq Y$** under some assumptions.

I am thinking that maybe Cantor set or irrationals could have similar property, but not very sure. Also I am not 100% sure if Cantor set and irrationals are strongly zero-dimensinal or just zero-dimensional.

Comment: The theorem is a so-called **characterisation** theorem. The left side gives **necessary** and **sufficient** conditions on a space $X$ (of which we suspect it might be homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q^\omega$) to check. So I don't see how it can apply to other spaces than $\Bbb Q^\omega$?

Comment: There are easy characterizations of some zero dimensional spaces such as the Cantor set (unique perfect compact metrizable zero dimensional space), the Baire space (unique zero dimensional completely metrizable separable space in which all compact sets have empty interior) and the rationals (unique countable metric space without isolated points), is this the kind of results you are looking for?

Comment: The Cantor set is not first category in itself and neither is the set of irrationals $\Bbb P$ so these immediately disqualify. For separable metric spaces zero-dimensional and strongly zero-dimensional are *always* equivalent.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti generalising such theorems was the whole point of van Engelen's thesis. The Cantor space is absolutely closed and the irrationals are an absolute $G_\delta$ (and both are separable metrisable and zero-dimensional) so it's reasonable (but hard!) to look for such theorems in higher Borel classes as well. The subclass of homogeneous such spaces is a good place to start. The quoted theorem was one of the results.

Comment: @Henno very interesting, I wasn't aware of the history there. Is it even clear/true that absolute $\Gamma^0_\alpha$ spaces exist for all $\alpha$ and $\Gamma=\Sigma,\Pi$ (all boldface)?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right, I re-formulated the question, so it is clear that I mean similar assumption, not the exact same.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I was looking for just similar characterization for different spaces, that have the property of strong zero-dimensionality. I am interested whether they are homeomorphic to other spaces under some cconditions. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti it’s a classic result in descriptive set theory that for every Borel class there is at least one separable zero-dimensional metric space of that ecaxt class. The one exception is “absolutely open” which is not a class that exists.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that's very interesting to me, do you happen to know where I can read more about this result? It's not mentioned in the DST books I'm familiar with as far as I can tell

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti it's folklore and well-known, probably spread over many classic papers by people like Kuratowski, Lusin, Souslin, etc etc. In lecture notes too I suppose. But not in many books I know. It's out of fashion now, too hard maybe?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Topologie I by Kuratowski (1928) covers some of it; read the original.. (I have a facsimile copy bought in Paris long ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I will mean by *space* a (non-empty) separable metrisable space.

For a *space* zero-dimensional and **strongly** zero-dimensional are equivalent, as is well known. So you can forget about that distinction in the remaining part.

Some classical theorems:

> (Brouwer (1910)) A *space* $X$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set $C$ iff it is zero-dimensional, has no isolated points (aka as "crowded" or dii, "dense-in-itself"), and is compact (i.e. absolutely closed).

> (Sierpiński (1920)) A *space* $X$ is homeomorphic to the rationals $\Bbb Q$ iff it is countable and crowded.

> (Aleksandrov and Urysohn (1928)) A *space* $X$ is homeomorphic to $C\setminus \{p\}$ (where $C$ is the Cantor set and $p$ any of its points) iff $X$ is zero-dimensional, locally compact, non-compact and crowded.

> (Aleksandrov and Urysohn (1928)) A *space* $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb P$ (the space of irrationals) iff $X$ is zero-dimensional, completely metrisable (which means it is an absolute $G_\delta$) and nowhere compact (which means that no point of $X$ has a compact neighbourhood; neighbourhood meant in the broad way).

> (Aleksandrov and Urysohn (1928)) A *space* $X$ is homeomorphic to $C \times \Bbb Q$ iff $X$ is zero-dimensional, $\sigma$-compact (so an absolute $F_\sigma$), which is nowhere compact and nowhere countable.

Then Aleksandrov and Urysohn asked (in their 1928 paper) for other characterisation theorems like this, but for higher Borel classes. Similar I think to what you want. So it's an old problem area.

If you want more info on some solutions to this see van Engelen's thesis which has proofs for all of the above too and his own characterisation of $\Bbb Q^\omega$ that you referenced. I won't repeat that info here. But it gets really technical and quite deep later on. (I've followed a one semester class/seminar on descriptive set theory by van Engelen during my studies).